# HDP 2.5 - Error is Kerberizing sandbox

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, jcs, hortonworks-sandbox, kdc

I'm trying to kerberize HDP 2.5, and getting error when using doing this...

Link being used to kerberize: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.1.1/bk_Ambari_Security_Guide/content/_installing_and_configuring_the_kdc.html

I've installed new KDC, and started it. Also, jcs has been setup.

On Ambari UI, i click the launch Kerberos UI, and fill in details of the KDC.

On clicking next, I get the error in - Install Kerberos Client

---

```
Caught an exception while executing custom service command: <class 'ambari_agent.AgentException.AgentException'>: 'Script /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/KERBEROS/1.10.3-10/package/scripts/kerberos_client.py does not exist'; 'Script /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/KERBEROS/1.10.3-10/package/scripts/kerberos_client.py does not exist'
```

---

Any ideas on this?

Note: I did not face this issue in HDP 2.4, which was kerberized successfully. Also, I'm using HDP 2.5 sandbox (using VirtualBox).